# WCF Interface not Implemented

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq, entity-framework

I am new to WCF and don't know what's wrong, I get the following error:

> WcfServiceLibrary.ReportServiceCO' does not implement interface member
>   'WcfServiceLibrary.IReport.GetAllOrdersForCustomer(int)'

The interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IReport 
{
   // [OperationContract]
   // List<ModelData> GetAllCustomer();
    [OperationContract]
    List<ORDER> GetAllOrdersForCustomer(int _customerid);
}
```

The class:

```
class ReportServiceCO : IReport
{

    public List<ORDER> GetAllORDERsForCustomer(int _customerid)
    {
        List<ORDER> orders = new List<ORDER>();
        TestEntities ent = new TestEntities();
        var orders3 = from x in ent.ORDERs
                      where x.CUSTOMERID == _customerid
                      select new { x.ORDERID, x.DATA, x.CUSTOMERID, x.VALOARE };
        foreach (var i in orders3)
        {
            ORDER o = new ORDER();
            o.ORDERID = i.ORDERID;
            o.CUSTOMERID = i.ORDERID;
            o.DATA = i.DATA;
            o.CUSTOMERID = i.CUSTOMERID;
            o.VALOARE = i.VALOARE;
            orders.Add(o);
        }
        return orders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method name is case sensitive:

In the `interface` is it declared as:

```
GetAllOrdersForCustomer
```

Yet the implementation is defined as:

```
GetAllORDERsForCustomer
```

It needs to be:

```
public List<ORDER> GetAllOrdersForCustomer(int _customerid) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename GetAllORDERsForCustomer to GetAllOrdersForCustomer.